# How to get previous clicked element in asp.net Gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I have a itemtemplate linkbutton inside gridview. i want to set clicked link button font bold in the `linkbutton_Onclick` event.

```
Protected Sub lblArtId_Onclick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim clickedRow As GridViewRow = TryCast(DirectCast(sender, LinkButton).NamingContainer, GridViewRow)
    lblArtId_temp_lnk = DirectCast(clickedRow.FindControl("lblArtId"), LinkButton)
    'ViewState("lblArtId_temp_lnk") = lblArtId_temp_lnk
    ' lblArtId_temp_lnk.Font.Bold = False
    Dim qry As String = ""
    Dim str_Qry As String = String.Empty
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
    Dim dt_new As DataTable = New DataTable
    Dim txt As String = ""
    Dim obj As GridViewGroup

    Dim lblArtId_lnk As LinkButton = DirectCast(clickedRow.FindControl("lblArtId"), LinkButton)

    If ViewState("lblArtId_temp_lnk_cnt") > 0 Then
        lblArtId_temp_lnk.Font.Bold = False
    End If

    ViewState("lblArtId_temp_lnk_cnt") += 1

End Sub
```

that is, the previous clicked link button set to normal and current clicked link button set to font bold
suggest me to get a solution.

thanks in advance